# HTML navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a project on creating a website but I'm having trouble with the navigation.
I want to make the navigation bar appear on the right-hand side I used `float: right;` in .top-nav li and the navigation bar came like a mirror image.
So my navigation bar is in this order. Home, Shop, Quiz, About Us, Gallery. Currently on the left-hand side

```css
.top-nav {
  background-color: rgb(56, 42, 65);
}

.top-nav ul {
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /*To remove the horizontal scroll bar came with ul*/
  text-align: center;
}

.top-nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 13px 20px;
}

.top-nav li a {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
}

.top-nav li a:hover {
  color: blueviolet;
  transition: 1s;
}

.top-nav li a.active {
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="Images/home-logo.jpeg" alt="Logo" width="60px">
  </div>

  <nav class="top-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#quiz">Quiz</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: So what is your question? Float your whole navigation on the right? `.top-nav` will need to float as well, not just the elements inside.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Very nice try to show us what you have done. Please, try  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float: right">. Also, .top-nav has to be floated right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

header{display: flex;justify-content: space-between;align-items: center;}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).